# Can't install PHP PDO

Tags: linux, centos, php.ini, php, pdo

I have now tried to install PHP PDO in 2 hours without any luck, and i have searched everywhere to get a solution - but without any luck.

```
yum install php-pdo
```

doesn't work and i cannot find extension = PDO in php.ini.

have tried updating

```
yum update
```

and cleaing it, nothing works. What to do?

I  have CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

```
  -bash-4.1# rpm -e rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release
  -bash-4.1# yum install php-pdo
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
   * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
   * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
  Setting up Install Process
  No package php-pdo available.
  Error: Nothing to do
  -bash-4.1# yum clean
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Error: clean requires an option: headers, packages, metadata, dbcache, plugins,       expire-      cache, rpmdb, all
  -bash-4.1# yum update
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
   * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
   * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
  Setting up Update Process
  No Packages marked for Update
  -bash-4.1# yum install php-pdo
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
   * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
   * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
  Setting up Install Process
  No package php-pdo available.
  Error: Nothing to do
  -bash-4.1# su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck       http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E       %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-      $(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Setting up Local Package Process
  Cannot open: http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-      %fedora.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
  Cannot open: http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-      %fedora.noarch.rpm. Skipping.
  Nothing to do
  -bash-4.1# su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/5/i386/rpmfusion-      free-release-5-1.noarch.rpm       ttp://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/5/i386/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-5-      1.noarch.rpm'
  Retrieving http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/5/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-5-1.noarch.rpm
  warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.d5nTQs: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID e74f0522: NOKEY
  error: open of ttp://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/5/i386/rpmfusion-nonfree-      release-5-1.noarch.rpm failed: No such file or directory
  -bash-4.1# su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck       http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm       http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/updates/6/i386/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-      1.noarch.rpm'
  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
  Setting up Local Package Process
  rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm                    | 5.9 kB     00:00     
  Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-ch9z50/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm: rpmfusion-      free-release-6-1.noarch
  Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-ch9z50/rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch.rpm to be installed
  Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
   * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
   * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
  rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm                 | 6.0 kB     00:00     
  Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-ch9z50/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm:       rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch
  Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-ch9z50/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch.rpm to be installed
  Resolving Dependencies
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:6-1 will be installed
  ---> Package rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:6-1 will be installed
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution

  Dependencies Resolved

  ================================================================================
   Package                 Arch   Version
                                      Repository                             Size
  ================================================================================
  Installing:
   rpmfusion-free-release  noarch 6-1 /rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch    3.7 k
   rpmfusion-nonfree-release
                           noarch 6-1 /rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch 3.8 k

  Transaction Summary
  ================================================================================
  Install       2 Package(s)

  Total size: 7.5 k
  Installed size: 7.5 k
  Is this ok [y/N]: y
  Downloading Packages:
  Running rpm_check_debug
  Running Transaction Test
  Transaction Test Succeeded
        Running Transaction
    Installing : rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch                            1/2 
    Installing : rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch                         2/2 
    Verifying  : rpmfusion-nonfree-release-6-1.noarch                         1/2 
    Verifying  : rpmfusion-free-release-6-1.noarch                            2/2 

  Installed:
    rpmfusion-free-release.noarch 0:6-1   rpmfusion-nonfree-release.noarch 0:6-1  

  Complete!
  -bash-4.1# yum updateLoaded plugins: fastestmirrorLoading mirror speeds from cached hostfile       * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
   * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
   * rpmfusion-free-updates: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
   * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
   * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
  rpmfusion-free-updates                                   | 2.7 kB     00:00     
  rpmfusion-free-updates/primary_db                        | 247 kB     00:00     
  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates                                | 2.2 kB     00:00     
  rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/primary_db                     |  46 kB     00:00     
  Setting up Update Process
  No Packages marked for Update
  -bash-4.1# yum install php-pdoLoaded plugins: fastestmirrorLoading mirror speeds from cached       hostfile * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
   * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
   * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
         * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
   * rpmfusion-free-updates: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
   * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
   * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
  Setting up Install Process
  No package php-pdo available.
  E      rror: Nothing to do
  -bash-4.1# /etc/yum.conf
  -bash: /etc/yum.conf: Permission denied
  -bash-4.1#
```

Comment: Kim. Welcome to serverfault. To help us help you, please get your OS version (cat /etc/redhat-release) if you are indeed on CentOS.  Also, what is the error message you get from yum.

Comment: That means i cannot install the package. It says No package pdo-mysql available.

Comment: I have CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Comment: Please run "yum repolist enabled" to see if what repos you have enabled.

Comment: check post for repolist

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Sorry, but [SF] is for Professional System Administrators (et al) only. Your question appears to be for non-professional use and might be on-topic on [SU] or [unix.SE], but you should search their sites and check their FAQs before posting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have installed RPM Fusion repositories for Fedora, rather than for Enterprise Linux. These would not be compatible with your CentOS system and therefore would cause this error.

To resolve the issue, remove the repos (e.g. `rpm -e rpmfusion-free-release rpmfusion-nonfree-release`) and [replace them with the correct repos](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration).

Then, check your `/etc/yum.conf` file and remove any inappropriate `exclude`s.

(The error 503 is a temporary failure and will resolve itself when the upstream fixes their web site. You can ignore that for now.)

Comment: I did your command. But i am completly newbie for server administration, how can i "replace them with the correct repos"?

Comment: Click the link, and download and install the correct files from that link.

Comment: It still says -bash-4.1# yum install php-pdo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * rpmforge: mirror.jgotteswinter.com
 * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
Setting up Install Process
No package php-pdo available.

Comment: Did you accidentally exclude some packages? Check your `/etc/yum.conf` file.

Comment: -bash: /etc/yum.conf: Permission denied

Comment: You need to _edit_ the file, not try to _run_ it.

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/1BjQMPSG is output

Comment: Yep, you have a bunch of stuff excluded that almost certainly shouldn't be. Just remove that `exclude=` line entirely.

Comment: Are you using cPanel/WHM by chance?  @Michael Many of these hosting management tools have these exclude lines as their software provides the RPMs.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Possibly, but if that were the case, then shouldn't you use cPanel's tools to install PHP and its modules instead?

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes you _should_ :)

Comment: Ok now i did install PDO, but it still not enabled. I did Installed:
  php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6   ... in php.ini i had extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
 but doesnt work still? Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you restart the web server/PHP?

Comment: Yes i did reboot my webserver

Comment: create a phpinfo file and access it from a browser to see if pdo is enabled. `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: It's not installed. /usr/local/lib/php.ini ... http://pointsafari.dk/phpinfo.php - i have made yum install php-pdo, it's right? I need more or what?

Comment: That's a completely different version of PHP than the one you installed with `yum`.

Comment: So what's next step, i am really stupid, can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: Your next step should be to hire someone with experience, or get some formal training. You've far exceeded what this site was meant for.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server behind a proxy or firewall?  The 503 error when trying to fetch:

```
https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64
```

Suggests your server cannot download the mirrorlist.

Since it cannot get the mirror list, it will not be able to find the RPM required.

You may want to see if you can fetch that URL using curl:

```
curl "https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=x86_64"
```

If you can then remove your added repos to get back to a standard configuration.

Comment: I have now made the curl... what to do next

Comment: Curl should have returned a mirror list.  If it did not, then you may have a networking issue.

Comment: It did, but what to do next?

Comment: Maybe your next step should be to either get some formal training or hire someone with some experience :-/